# .NET assembly not creating as backgrouond process using System.Process

Tags: .net, process, c++-cli, ipc, system.diagnostics

I am trying to launch background processes using `System.Diagnostic.Process` API. It launches every all native and windows form base processes such as notepad.exe, but this is unable to launch pure managed GUI-less assemblies. Task Manager is not showing those assemblies listed in its list as seperate processes, and neither exceptions nor error codes occur.

Is there any other way to launch background processes on demand using `Process.Start` for pure managed assemblies visible in task manager?

Comment: You mean console applications or a winforms-application without a main window?

Answer (score 2):

Use Task Manager's Processes tab, not the Applications tab.  The latter one only lists processes that have a window.  Also consider that the process simply exited quickly after starting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a managed assembly, you should check out the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class

Comment: It tells if somehow your GUI processes facing interrupts and hindrances then you can create some background processes allied with seperate thread. I wnat my processes to be launch on demand as child processes which Process.Start doing perfectly with Windows.Forms and other Native processes. But when pure managed assemblies needs to be launch as background seprate processes visible to task manager , it does'nt launch them and task manager unable to show them

Comment: Thnx alot everybody..
actually it go aways after creating. I put message box and everything fine.